# pandas loc and then iloc for to select specific columns and row doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
>>>> wavelength     veg     asph      veg1    asph1  
band
B1    449.9           0.037   0.055    0.63    0.75
B2    496.6           0.044   0.063    0.48    0.76
B3    560.0           0.08    0.073    0.45    0.66
...
```

I want to create x and y variables for each band index, e.g

```
Xb1=[0.63 ,0.75]
Yb1=[ 0.037 ,0.055]

Xb2=[0.48  ,0.76]
Yb2=[ 0.044 ,0.063]
```

*the "b1" and "b2" are just to make it easier to understand from which row th enumbers are coming from.

I have tried to select only one row and then the specific numbers by using loc and iloc like this:

```
bnd=['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B9','B10','B11','B12']
#df=df.set_index('bands')

for b in bnd:
    print(b)
    x=df.loc[b].iloc[:,3:].astype(str).astype(float)
    y=df.loc[b].iloc[:,1:3].astype(str).astype(float)
```

But I get this error message:

> IndexingError: Too many indexers

I couldn't dins yet the way to write it in correct way so I get those numbers.

**My end goal here is to be able to get the correct numbers for X and y** in order to calculate the linear regression between the two (in other words: I want to determine X and y in order to calculate linear regression for each index).

edit:

the x and y should be inserted into this part to calculate the linear regression:

```
# Fit with polyfit
b, m = polyfit(x, y, 1)
plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.title('B1')
plt.plot(x, b + m * x, '-')
plt.show()
print('m:',m , 'b:',b)
```

so they should be numerical

Comment: @BillHuang I have edited it

Comment: @BilHuang b1 and b2 relates to the row, I put it there to be easy to understand fro mwhich row the numebrs are coming from

Comment: what about df.to_dict('index') ? the index will be key and the value will be another dict, with column name as key

Comment: do you need the these variable in list ?

Comment: @Qamar Abbas yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get error if you just modify inputs of iloc :

```
bnd=['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B9','B10','B11','B12']
#df=df.set_index('bands')

for b in bnd:
    print(b)
    x=df.loc[b].iloc[3:].astype(str).astype(float)
    y=df.loc[b].iloc[1:3].astype(str).astype(float)
```

if you are trying to save the elements of row in list then may be this code can work for you:

```
list_req=[]
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
     xe,ye=row['veg1'],row['asph1']
     temp_list=[xe, ye]
     list_req.append(temp_list)


print(list_req)
[[0.63 ,0.75],[0.48  ,0.76]......]
```

if its is helpful then Similarly you can do this for other columns